# How to change background of one item from listview in code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have inherited ListActivity and I need to change in code background color of some rows. How to do that, for example first row to set YELLOW background ?

```
public class AlarmsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Activity currentActivity;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.alarms, DATA));

        currentActivity = this;

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }

    static final String[] DATA = new String[] {"Name","Last Name","Address","City" };


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take some array of colors and then in getView method set the view color to the pos. for example :

```
private int[] colors=new int[]{0xfffff000, 0xffff0000, .....};
```

in **getView()** write this:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(colors[pos]);
```

here pos is the index value in the **colors[]**