# How to change color of ListView Item in a ListFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, background-color, android-listfragment

I would like to change the background color of each item in the ListView. I am using a ListFragment instead of a ListActivity so when I import the getView() method I get the following:

```
    @Override
public View getView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getView();
}
```

So I cannot use the typical

```
view.setBackGroundColor(myColors[position]);
```

since the method does not have a position or view passed through it. Do I need to put those values into the method, remove the @Override and then call the method myself? If so where do I need to call it?

Can I accomplish this by setting up some type of listselector where the selector.xml file has a pressed state and an unpressed state that I can control in my java class?

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29 it's for getting 'the root view for the fragment's layout', not list items view.

Comment: So you want to change the row's background when its pressed?

Comment: Sorry slight typo I want to change the color of the ListView Items. Corrected above. This is the page I was looking at when talking about the getView() method and the view.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_ARRAY). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137791/how-to-change-background-of-one-item-from-listview-in-code