# How do you passively change the background of a single item in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, background, android-calendar

I'm writing a piece of code with a schedule listed in a listview. The intention is to change the background of a certain item in the listview between a certain time. For example when its 3:40, the item that says 3:00-4:00 will have a green background and when it becomes 4:00, the background will go back to white. Any ideas on how to do this? Here's my relevant code so far.

```
    final ListView schedule = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schedule);
    String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.friday_schedule);
    schedule.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myKeys));
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    if(hour<6&&hour>5)
    {
        schedule.item(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
```

Also for reference, this is a similiar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137791/how-to-change-background-of-one-item-from-listview-in-code). And just tell me if i forgot to attach some of my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating a subclass of `ArrayAdapter` that overrides `getView()`.  `getView()` would have some logic like this:

```
...
final ListView schedule = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.schedule);
String[] myKeys = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.friday_schedule);
schedule.setAdapter(new ScheduleAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myKeys));
...

public static class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] schedule) {
        super(context, resource, schedule);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        // compare current clock hour to the hour this item represents
        boolean isCurrentHour = position == ... <your logic goes here>
        view.setBackgroundResource(isCurrentHour ? R.color.current_hour : R.color.normal_hour);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Then, on the hour, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, and the `ListView` will redraw with the colors changed.

Here I'm showing `ScheduleAdapter` as an inner class of your activity with the `ListView`.

Comment: If I make a subclass of ArrayAdapter, does it:
a) have to have a specific name
b) have to have more than just the getView method?
And also, how would i link the subclass to my listview? would schedule.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(className, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myKeys)); work?

Comment: You have to give your subclass a name; it can be any name, but by convention, it would be something like `ScheduleAdapter`.  If you can figure out the hour from the list position, then you shouldn't need more than a constructor and a `getView()` override.  I updated my answer with some example code.

Comment: I think you meant to write ScheduleAdapter instead of arrayadapter for the constructor. Right?

Comment: Yeah, I did, oops.  :(

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your code works almost seamlessly- the only problems left are because of my logic. I've accepted your answer but one last thing. Can you explain this line?
view.setBackgroundResource(isCurrentHour ? R.color.current_hour : R.color.normal_hour);
Im not familiar with the presented syntax.

Comment: Java has something called a *ternary operator* that you can think of as an if/then/else in a single expression.  So you have:  <boolean-expr> ? <expr-if-true> : <expr-if-false>.

Comment: I like using these in `getView()` because of view recycling.  If you forget to set a property because you forgot an `else` statement, you can end up with views that look wrong because of a property value from the view before it was recycled.